# Pointing class property to another class with vectors

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference, vector

I've got a simple class, and another class that has a property that points to the first class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class first{
public:
    int var1;
};

class second{
public:
    first* classvar;
};
```

Then, i've got a void that's supposed to point "classvar" to the intended iteration of the class "first".

```
void fill(vector<second>& sec, vector<first>& fir){
    sec[0].classvar = &fir[0];
}
```

Finally the main(). Create and fill a vector of class "first", create "second" vector, and run the fill function.

```
int main(){

    vector<first> a(1);
    a[0].var1 = 1000;

    vector<second> b(1);

    fill(b, a);

    cout << b[0].classvar.var1 << '\n';

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
1>c:\...\main.cpp(29) : error C2228: left of '.var1' must have class/struct/union
1>        type is 'first *'
```

And I can't figure out why it reads the "classvar" as the whole vector instead of just the single instance. Should I do this

```
cout << b[0].classvar[0].var1 << '\n';
```

it reads perfectly.

Can anyone figure out the problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `b[0].classvar` is a pointer.  To access members of a class through a pointer, you must use the `->` operator, not `.`.

The reason `b[0].classvar[0].var1` works is because the index operator `[]` for pointers makes this equivalent to `(*(b[0].classvar + 0)).var1`.  In other words, it adds 0 to the pointer and then dereferences it, so you can then access it with the dot operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << b[0].classvar->var1 << '\n';
```

`b[0].classvar` is a pointer.  Your current code should be valid with that fix, but make sure you don't invalidate the pointer later.

Answer (score 0):

```
b[0].classvar->var1
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
cout << b[0].classvar.var1 << '\n';
```

should be

```
cout << b[0].classvar->var1 << '\n';
```

since second's classvar is a pointer to first.

This

```
b[0].classvar[0].var1
```

works due to the equivalence of pointers & arrays in C & C++.